# What would cause Hibernate performance to fluctuate in a nondeterminisic way?

Tags: java, performance, hibernate

I have a project where we run a nightly performance test. It's the same test every night where our website is hit by hundreds of concurrent "users" for 3 hours.  The performance results end up in one of two states - bad or good, and each state seems to be consistent with itself. Our database guy (oracle btw) noticed that on the days of bad performance we would have many, many more calls than on the good days, but only of one query.

From my analysis so far I think it has to do with hibernate choosing to use/not use proxies, but I cannot understand what would direct hibernate to do so on some days and not on others. What would cause such erratic non-deterministic behaviour in Hibernate? I am on Hibernate 4.2.0, and spring. We are not using a 2nd level cache. There are no other applications on our servers.

The object that causes this call to be emitted is at the end of a long chain of object that are related via parent/child. We are working a the head of this chain.

[image: Bad performance]
A bad run, notice 4m executions of the 9wu... query

[image: A night of good performance]
A good run, notice 630k executions of the 9wu... query

Edit: I am not able to mostly reproduce this in a module. It appears that when I have -xmx set very low (28m), the extra calls are not there, but at xmx = 128m I get it most runs. Any tips on where in Hibernate I can see why/how it would decide on if it should proxy or not?

Edit 2: I am not able to reproduce consistently in my module. It will work great for 5 runs then fail for 3 then work then fail. Every time I am running the exact same unit test. It does appear to be an N+1 problem, it loads a bunch of children through the "select item0..." query, but during a good run it decides to use another query or it doesn't discard the entries from between webservice calls. I will see what I can do to obfuscate my objects and provide some details. IT is unfortunately a tree stored in a database, and it uses inheritance with a discriminator.

Comment: I am interested on your "From my analysis so far I think it has to do with hibernate choosing to use/not use proxies".  What "Proxy" are you referring to? If you are talking about the proxy for entities, I have never heard that Hibernate is creating proxies in a non-deterministic manner.  May you further elaborate on this?

Comment: it seems to me that it is something like: 1. You left the long chain of object all lazy fetched.  2. In some case, you are simply navigating small part of your chain (which is the good case), while in some case you are navigating most of the chain, which cause huge amount of lazy fetch (which is the bad case). 3. or, in some special case you are doing some "un-reusable n+1" fetching.  I strong recommend you to have proper logging in Hibernate, and investigate in what case there are huge amount of SQL generated (that should be obvious)

Comment: could you post your mappings related to the query? I'd suggest you enable eager fetch on the mapping and see if that "such erratic non-deterministic behavior" still exist or not

Comment: Adrian - Yes we see hibernate sometimes use javassist and sometimes not. This has caused issues, we are using something similar to the Proxy Visitor pattern to work around it. https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ProxyVisitorPattern?_sscc=t I think you are right about a long chain of object marked lazy, but I can tell you that the navigation is exactly the same each time. "proper logging in hibernate" what do you mean? I have the SQL logging turned on, but I can't seem to figure out why hibernate chooses one path. Strong - See Edit 2, the graph is complex and there are many many lazy connections.

Comment: Are you using query cache?

Comment: Are your tests determistic? Is the database state before your tests always the same? Do you use multi-threading while testing?

Answer (score 4):

It's hard, of course, to say why this might be happening.  However, there are some good resources out there for [optimizing performance in Hibernate and debugging problems with it](http://blog.f12.no/wp/2010/02/16/hibernate-performance-and-optimization/).

In the linked article the author suggests that the best way to diagnose performance issues is using [YourKit Java Profiler](http://www.yourkit.com/).  If your load and performance environment is remote and you can't run a profiler locally [you can attach one remotely](http://www.yourkit.com/docs/95/help/attach_wizard.jsp).  Of course, running a profiler has some overhead so you might find your perforance characteristics changed because you have one attached.  Still, this is probably your best bet for tracking down what is going on.

Other useful links:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/debugging-hibernate-generated
http://jroller.com/jcarreira/date/20050223#hibernate_tips

Comment: Thanks those are great links, I have used yourkit previously but the problem seems to lie within hibernate. I will be getting the hibernate sources.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Oracle is 9 or less maybe your database is destroyed you can export and import your database just for case
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/detect-and-correct-corruption.php

Comment: Sadly that is not it. Our nightly runs are against an Oracle II DB, and my unit tests use an in memory Derby DB which is recreated each run.